# Thumbnail's background color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using a **Thumbnail**. In the iconfinder image, the `cross` is transparent and takes the background color of the main `container`.

I want the cross to be white and the surrounding to be black.

```
export const Screen: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.iconsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.cross}>
          <Thumbnail
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#323443',
    flex: 1,
  },
cross: {
    paddingTop: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    zIndex: 100,
  },

});
```

If I add a background color to `cross` or the `TouchableOpacity`, a block of white appears which goes beyond the thumbnail. How else can I achieve this?

If I add a style to the thumbnail itself:

```
  thumbnail:{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  }
```

I get this, and this is not what I want. I don't want the border outline.

[image]

Thumbnail:
https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/close-512.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a border outline ... try decreasing the radius of the icon container/white area to match the radius of the png file you are using.